# Sync between two windows phone devices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a project wherein i have to create a windows mobile app which synchronize files between two windows phone, provided that the connectivity between two phone should be through WiFi.

Being new to this app development field , i have no idea on where to start and where to look. Is there any sample application present to sync data between two phones without involving any database. And what API should i use. i referred to some tutorials on [this website](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible without a server between both phones. Microsoft is very restrictive and won't let you access the WiFi connection. Actually you would have to use one of the phones as a WiFi hotspot and the other one as client and this is definitely not possible with an WP app.

I would recommend to write a Windows Service (have a look at WCF) which both phones connect to. This service would have to do all the work which would be:

- Wait for phone requests to work with them
- Handle the request when a phone wants to synchronize data
- Let the second phone know that there are new data to receive
- Transfer data to the second phone

Actually there will be more requirements for such a service (e.g. security) you will have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Yet, there is a solution because Rudy Huyn connected several Windows phone using the connection Wifi without server http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rl0VHkoOHTA
But I don't know how..

Comment: I just knew that he was using UDP socket